# Serve subpath file in Restify

Tags: node.js, restify

I am using Restify in Node to serve static img file, here is my code:

```
import * as Restify from "restify";
server.use(Restify.plugins.bodyParser());
server.use(Restify.plugins.queryParser());
server.get("/hostedImages/:file", HostedImagsHandler);
async function HostedImagsHandler(req: Restify.Request, res: Restify.Response, next) {
  const path: string = req.params[1];
  return next();
}
```

When I run this, I can serve file like this:

```
http://localhost:5512/hostedImages/test.png
```

However, I can't serve any file that is in a subdirectory:

```
http://localhost:5512/hostedImages/test/test.png
```

How do I serve subfolder?  I am running Restify 8.3.3 so regex routing don't work.

Answer (score 1):

They did away with regex support for routing in version 7. You accomplish what you want with two routes:

```
server.get("/hostedImages/:file", HostedImagsHandler);
server.get("/hostedImages/*/:file", HostedImagsHandler);
```

The first handles paths like:

http://localhost:5512/hostedImages/test.png

The second handle paths like:

http://localhost:5512/hostedImages/test/test.png

And paths nested as as you like beneath that. They have to be specified in that order or the top level handler doesn't work.

This seems like a corner case, but it also seems like a quirk in the framework. I would expect ""/hostedImages/*/:file" path would handle the top level path, but it doesn't.

Comment: It's so odd they did away with something so basic, I will use this

Comment: I only worked for one level down, it didn't work on subsubfolder unfortunately.  I'll still use it for my current project, but I didn't want to mark it as the correct answer

Comment: I thought when I tested it here it worked. But I just realized I tested it using express!  I will revise the answer, or just get rid of it!